# How to get quad1.r into R

Tags: r

I would like to solve a quadratic formula but I can't get the "quad1.r" into R. 
source(quad1.r) 
just tried something like that but it didn't quite work out.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean `source(quad1.r)` or `source("quad1.r")`? Note the quotes.

Comment: I mean source(quad1.r)

Comment: So it should be `source("quad1.r")`, if `quad1.r` is in the current/working directory.

Comment: Ok, it still does not work, Idk why I can't get it in.

Comment: So please share any error message in your question. It is hard to understand what doesn't work. However, where is located the function `quad1.r` and what is the output of `getwd()`?

Comment: What's your working directory (`getwd()`)? Set it to the folder that has the file `quad1.r` - `setwd("~/path/to/folder/")` - then `source` the file `source("quad1.r")`. Make sure case is correct (`quad1.R`?). If it "doesn't quite work out", please share *why* you think that - how are you testing that it works, are there any errors or warnings, what do they say...

Comment: We can't help you further without requested information.